# How can I change the base URL of an AngularJS HTTP call?

Tags: angularjs

My application calls $HTTP many times like this:

```
    this.$http({
        method: this.method,
        url: this.url
    })
```

The this.url is always set to something like /app/getdata

Now I have moved the back-end of my application to another server and I will need to get data like this:

```
https://newserver.com/app/getdata
```

Is there a way that I can supply a base URL that will be used for all the $http calls?

Comment: Set your baseUrl somewhere in app.js and use `baseUrl+this.url` wherever required. Something like `var baseUrl = "newserver.com/";`.

Comment: If your back-end is on different server than the angular app, you might also have use Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: You may see Restangular - there you can change base_url with one method. http://compassinhand.com/2015/08/05/multiple-restangular-api-base-urls-made-easy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to keep my urls close to where they are needed. So if I have a service, then I'd keep the base url there; like this: `this.rootUrl = '/api/v1/';`

This allows me to have additional contextual methods that 'extend' the url.

For example:

```
this.getBaseUrl = function(client_id, project_id) {
    return this.rootUrl + 'clients/' + client_id + '/projects/' + project_id + '/';
};
```

Which I can then use like this:

```
this.createActivity = function(client_id, project_id, activity_name, callback) {
    $http.post(this.getBaseUrl(client_id, project_id) + 'activities', {activity: {name: activity_name}})
        .success(callback)
        .error(this.handlerError);
};
```

or like this (within the same service):

```
this.closeActivity = function(activity_id, callback){
    $http.get(this.rootUrl + 'close_activity/' + activity_id)
        .success(callback)
        .error(this.handlerError);
};
```

Answer (score 21):

I found a alternative solution instead of `<base>` tag:
written in coffeescript

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push ($q)->
  'request': (config)->
    if config.url.indexOf('/api') is 0
      config.url = BASE_URL+config.url
    config
```

Comment: This kind of approach is much more appealing to me. I'd prefer interception to lots of injecting constants into my services.

Comment: Can someone point me to some documentation to understand how I may use this?

Answer (score 7):

I usually keep settings in angular constants and inject them to services.

Answer (score -4):

set baseUrl in `$rootScope`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.baseUrl = "https://newserver.com";
});
```

add `$rootScope` into your app's controllers:

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    ...

this.$http({
    method: this.method,
    url: $rootScope.baseUrl + this.url
})
```

Comment: This is very poor design. It attaches the shared configuration to an object which exposes hundreds of unrelated concerns. At least use `app.value('baseUrl', 'https://newserver.com');` and inject that.