# AngularJS - Best way to provide HTTP URLs at run time

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application, which is supposed to call several Spring-based REST API's, url of which would be dynamic based on the environment. 
Like if I am running on dev environment, REST URL would be `localhost:7777/..`
If on production, it would be `productionserver:7777/...`.

Now I have to provide these API URLs to Angular.
What is the best way to configure these REST URLs at run time in my AngularJS application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the base URL of an AngularJS HTTP call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315265/how-can-i-change-the-base-url-of-an-angularjs-http-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place all of your api configuration into a single json file named for example config.json, and then before application is bootstrapped you can fetch that data and make a constant out of it and after inject it anywhere you need, something like the following:

Lets say config.json contains these values:

```
{
 "ApiUrls": {
   "ApiUrl1": "value1",
   "ApiUrl2": "value2",
   "ApiUrl3": "value3"
  }
}
```

Injecting configuration api urls before bootstrapping:

```
(function () {
fetchData().then(bootstrapApp);

function fetchData() {
    var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

    return $http.get("config.json").then(function (response) {
        app.constant("ApiConfiguration", response.data.ApiUrls);
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        alert(errorResponse);
        // Handle error case
    });
}

function bootstrapApp() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
}
}());
```

and for example your service:

```
app.factory('factory', factory);

factory.$inject = ['ApiConfiguration'];

function factory(ApiConfiguration){
   var serviceFactory = {
     ApiUrl1: ApiConfiguration.ApiUrl1
   }
   return serviceFactory;
}
```

This way you can set your values inside the config.json file as per enviroment. Locally it will be `localhost:7777/..`, in production it will be `productionserver:7777/...` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Create Service for rest urls or REST Data:-

```
 (function () {
var injectParams = ['$location'];
var service = function ($location) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.baseUrl = 'http://' + $location.host() +':'+$location.port() + '/api/v1/';
    return vm;
};
//bootstrapping
service.$inject = injectParams;
angular.module('showdown').service('restURL', service);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you may want to inject your URLs via [ng-init](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-init.asp). Just make sure to JS and HTML escape the string, if necessary.

So your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="
    myUrl='${myUrl?html?js_string}';
    myUrl2='${myUrl2?html?js_string}';">
```

And your Javascript would look something like this:

```
angular.controller("myApp", () => ($scope) => {
    $scope.myUrl; //url is here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a const in ur app like SERVER-ENV and write a build task to change the value of this constant based on the server environment.
Now you can create URL using this const e.g. SERVER-ENV + "";
This task can be automated with gulp or grunt.

Comment: `const SERVER-ENV;`? You'll need to be more specific and provide a piece of code in your answer. Also, OP does not mention any possibility of gulp or grunt in the solution. It asks *run time*, which excludes building tools.